# How to set Content Security Policy in Windows Universal apps

Tags: javascript, win-universal-app, windows-10

I don't even know if that's what I need, but after several days of this [MSDN Forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/61723fa8-15b4-4853-88f4-351a6d6ec35f/uwphtml-is-script-in-the-head-now-disabled?forum=wpdevelop) with no answers at all I thought I'd give a shot in SO.

**My problem**: I have many Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 HTML/Javascripts apps that have a little `<script>` sentence in the `<head>` of every html page. I started migrating my apps to Windows 10 as a single Universal Windows app but I get the following error:

```
CSP14312: Resource violated directive 'script-src ms-appx: data: 'unsafe-eval'' in Host Defined Policy: inline script. Resource will be blocked
```

and of course, nothing gets executed... am I missing anything?

**edit:** To repro just create a blank Windows Universal app with VS2015 RC and add

```
<script>
    console.log('hello');
</script>
```

right before the head tag closes

Comment: Can you provide a minimal repro?

This should work in general.

Comment: can somebody explain why the down vote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rob has it right, by default you can't have inline script in **ms-appx:///** protocol.  This is the default protocol for an application and has a default CSP policy that doesn't allow inline script.

If you really wish to use inline script you can navigate to the content via **ms-appx-web:///** protocol where there is no default CSP policy.

The one note is that you do not have access to some capabilities in this protocol.

The only difference I have beyond what Rob said is that you most likely want to set the Application Content URI Rule (ACUR) like this

```
<uap:ApplicationContentUriRules>
   <uap:Rule Type="include" Match ="ms-appx-web:///" WindowsRuntimeAccess="all"/>
</uap:ApplicationContentUriRules>
```

To navigate to your content you can set the StartPage in the manifest to **ms-appx-web:///default.html**

Comment: Isn't that exactly what Rob suggested? couple of questions, 1) this is brand new to Win10 right? inline scripting was OK in Win8.1 2) adding what you suggested I can't access `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current` is that expected?

Comment: Sorry I updated my example. You need to add WindowsRuntimeAccess="all"

Comment: For Windows 8 you were able to use inline script, but you were not able to easily change innerHTML, or dynamically add some types of attributes.  Overwhelmingly we heard that this was an issue. So we took out the previous security model of SafeHTML and went with the W3C standard of CSP.  For local content the only restriction is no inline script. We did create an [NPM module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/noin) that will help you remove inline script if you don't want to do it on your own.  Or you can simply use the web based protocol of ms-apps-web:///

Comment: great, that's exactly the kind of answer/comment I was expecting! welcome to SO ;)

Comment: Damn you Microsoft, never making things easy for developers!!! Can't you just copy from the others e.g. using sandboxig for apps just like Android? Always coming with new weird security models that nobody understands and with such an horrible documentation, and then everybody breaks into your systems the same...
Anyway this solution ain't working for me, and the same code ran on 8.1 without issues. Cordova app, universal app solution in VS 2015 after updating to Win 10. I always get CSP14312 :/

Comment: La Muerte Peluda, are you just trying to bring an 8.1 Cordova app to Windows 10? The security model is a W3C standard, we moved away from a Microsoft specific implementation to support a standard way of securing web content.

Comment: How would you define it on a Win8.1?   I added this child element to the Application-element:<ApplicationContentUriRules>
        <Rule Type="include" Match ="ms-appx-web:///"/>
      </ApplicationContentUriRules>
But I get an error message: "Error 8 App manifest contains invalid content URI rule 'ms-appx-web:///'"

Comment: I went the way of setting the startpage to "ms-appx-web:///default.html" but that in turn caused the following problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436947/windows-uwp-application-lifecycle-how-to-prevent-reload-in-js-html-css-app
The moment I revert it back to startpage="default.html" the problem in the link above is non-existent but I run into this very original problem. Just saying.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that's not your real use case, but overall it depends on the specific script whether it will work in the local or web context. See [Features and restrictions by context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465373.aspx) for an overview. If you can pull the script into a local JS file instead of calling it from the head then I would recommend that rather than fiddling with the app's security contexts.

Your console.log example works if it runs from the package (as you note) or if it runs in the web context. You can force the entire app to run in the web context by changing the start page to ms-appx-web:///default.html in the manifest.

However, since the app's now in the restricted web context it won't have access to all of the Windows Runtime. You can open that up by adding the following to the Application section in your manifest:

```
<uap:ApplicationContentUriRules>
   <uap:Rule Type="include" Match ="ms-appx-web:///" WindowsRuntimeAccess="allowForWebOnly"/>
</uap:ApplicationContentUriRules>
```

You'll need to open the manifest in a code editor rather than in the manifest editor to modify this section.

For more on the error see the Edge [Console error and status codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn706041(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation

Comment: I added what you suggested and it did work but I can't access the Windows Runtime :(

Answer (score 2):

Were you able to resolve this issue? I do apps and game development using the Enyo framework and encountered the same issue.  I was able to resolve it by entering the lines that I normally enter on the  tag on the default.js file on this section:

```
        if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
            // TODO: This application has been newly launched. Initialize your application here.
            initializemyapp();
            console.log("starting");
        } else {
            // TODO: This application was suspended and then terminated.
            // To create a smooth user experience, restore application state here so that it looks like the app never stopped running.
        }
```

Maybe it is a little to late, but hope this helps.

Comment: I did solve it doing exactly what you did... I added my script inside a js file and just added a reference to that file from the html