# Registering onclick event inside HTML in Universal Windows App (JS/HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, win-universal-app

I am building a **Universal Windows App** on *Windows 10* and *Visual Studio 2015*. When I register an event on any HTML control like a button, It does not fire its JavaScript function when event occurs.

```
<html>
 <head>
    <script> 
         function testClick() {
            document.getElementById("testOutput").innerText = "Hello again";}
    </script>    
 </head>

 <body>
    <div id="testOutput">Hello</div>
    <button id="btnTest" onclick="testClick()">Click Me</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

But it works when I register the event inside the JavaScript using *addEventListener*.

```
var button = document.getElementById("btnTest");
button.addEventListener("click", testClick, false);
```

According to MSDN I can add the event in either HTML or JavaScript: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441312.aspx

**What's wrong in registering the event in HTML?**

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: The JS function I set in the onclick is not being called.

Comment: Its working here: http://jsfiddle.net/kudd1hgc/

Comment: Yes, it works in a regular html page. But I am talking about a Universal Windows App

Comment: It's because inline script is blocked by Content Security Policy (CPS). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31051437/how-to-set-content-security-policy-in-windows-universal-apps

Answer (score 1):

Inline javaScript is not working with Universal Windows App.
Below code is working for me it is using JQuery.

```
$(document).on('click', '.openMenuClick',function () {

 });
```